# Metric tensor vs metric space.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, general-relativity, special-relativity

In special relativity the metric is expressed as

$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$

I have questions.

0- is this the metric tensor or the space metric? I am confused here, i.e. what is the differenence between them?

1-is this flat metric?

2- does the speed light $c^2$ coming from some special relativity equations?

3- what would happen if I dropped the minus sign in front of the speed of light and make all sings of the metric positive?

4- Now is this the same metric used in general relativity? I guess no, but in any event, could the metric expressed in form like above relating the all coordinates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(ds)^2$ is an infinitesimal [line element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_element). In 2-D Cartesian coordinates an infinitesimal displacement is given by Pythagoras theorem such that $(ds)^2=dx^2 + dy^2$. So the 4-D spacetime you reference is a generalisation of this where the factor of $c^2$ is incorporated for dimensional purposes. The metric tensor $g_{\alpha \beta}$ and associated components are the individual relativistic potentials associated with a spacetime. So for the spacetime you mention above the metric tensor is given by

$$ g_{\alpha \beta} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}. $$

The metric represents the 4-D flat spacetime associated with special relativity. In GR the components of the metric tensor are more complicated however, as the radial component $r \rightarrow\infty$ you should recover the flat spacetime given above. So, yes it represents flat space.

You *can* drop the minus sign, however you then need to change all the spatial components to be negative, otherwise the line element doesn't make sense. Think about the displacement of a photon in the sense that I described above for an infinitesimal displacement (We always refer to photons due to the first postulate of relativity being that the speed of light is $c$ for all observers).